# How I can set address of WCF service from client's command line when using spring.net

Tags: wcf, configuration, spring.net, object-address

My WCF service can work on any servers. My client - is console application. In command line parameters I want set address of my WCF service. 
Current in config client I have:

```
...
<spring>
    <context>
      <resource uri="assembly://MyAssembly.Console/MyAssembly.Console/ServerWeb.xml"/>
    </context>
  </spring>
...
<system.serviceModel>
 <client>
      <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="serverWebDataServiceEndpoint" address="http://localhost/mydata/DataService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding1" contract="MyData.Contracts.IDataService"/>
    </client>
...
```

File ServerWeb.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net"
         xmlns:wcf="http://www.springframework.net/wcf">

  <wcf:channelFactory id="serverWebDataService"
    channelType="VimpelCom.Fmrad.Theseus.WcfDataLayer.CommonTypes.Contracts.IDataService, VimpelCom.Fmrad.Theseus.WcfDataLayer.CommonTypes"
    endpointConfigurationName="serverWebDataServiceEndpoint" />

</objects>
```

In application, I use next code, for call service's methods:

```
IApplicationContext _ctx = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
IDataService _dataService = _ctx["serverWebDataService"] as IDataService;

var rule = _dataService.GetRuleById(ruleId);
```

How I can use another address of WCF service from command line?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that :

```
<wcf:channelFactory id="serverWebDataService"
    channelType="VimpelCom.Fmrad.Theseus.WcfDataLayer.CommonTypes.Contracts.IDataService, VimpelCom.Fmrad.Theseus.WcfDataLayer.CommonTypes"
    endpointConfigurationName="serverWebDataServiceEndpoint">
  <!-- You can use classic DI to configure the ChannelFactory<T> instance -->
  <wcf:property name="Endpoint.Address">
    <object type="System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress, System.ServiceModel">
      <constructor-arg name="uri" value"${serviceUrl}"/>
    </object>
  </wcf:property>
</wcf:channelFactory>
```

You can use IVariableSource abstraction to get a property value from commandline. See :
http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-variablesource

```
<object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.VariablePlaceholderConfigurer, Spring.Core">
   <property name="VariableSources">
      <list>
         <object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.CommandLineArgsVariableSource, Spring.Core">
           <property name="ArgumentPrefix" value="--" />
           <property name="ValueSeparator" value="="/>
         </object>
      </list>
   </property>
</object>
```

Set the variable in command line like this :
program.exe --serviceUrl=http://localhost/Service.svc